# Does "I think I've sh-- myself" mean the same as "I think I've sh-- my pants"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Sorry for the topic.

1. I think I've sh-- myself.
2. I think I've sh-- my pants.

Does the first mean the same as the second?

Comment: To shit oneself is more general. You can shit yourself whatever the circumstances, but to shit your pants you need to be wearing some.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey if you are insisting on the practicalities to the degree you seem to, then I could point out that in lack of wearing pants, the alternative would probably be not shitting oneself, but rather, shitting the floor. (Unless, on a second thought, if sitting in the meanwhile, which could involve somewhat different results (involving, I anticipate, shitting the sitting surface _and_ oneself in the same go. I wonder which turn of English could express _that_).) Interesting topic, nevertheless!

Comment: While indicating the fact that I speak English as a second/foreign language, +1 for "shat", in past tense.

Comment: @Levente the expression for "the sitting surface and oneself" is I've shat all over the place. :D (This is only funny if you know that "shitting all over" means "to ruin other people's ideas or plans with hostile criticism".)

Comment: Idiomatically, they're the same.  Literally (as Michael Harvey points out), there is a subtle difference.  In the majority of cases, you use the expression idiomatically (to indicate fear).  Also, as it is colloquial, often the 'my' will be replaced by the (ungrammatical) 'me' - in both 'meself', and 'me pants'.

Comment: There is also the possibility of metaphoric use of the first example. "I shat myself as the Boss read the report, and started frowning" does not mean a dirty backside, just extreme nervousness.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So, taking off one pants, dumping them on the floor, and squatting over them means something magical is going to happen to keep the pants clean?

Comment: @Abigail - no, simply that we should call that 'shitting **on** your pants'.

Comment: @mcalex I don't think I've ever heard an American use "me" like that. It sounds stereotypically Irish or Cockney.

Comment: @Barmar agreed, though not just Cockney, most of UK, plus AU (also pirates - 'shiver me timbers, arrrr').  US would probably be 'muh-self', or 'muh pants'

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the meanings are practically equivalent. Michael Harvey makes an argument that one can always shit *oneself* but can only shit *one's pants* if one is wearing pants to begin with; a counterargument is that if one is not wearing pants, it's more likely to shit *the floor* rather than *oneself*. In the event one is wearing pants the distinction is slight, but someone lying in a hospital bed wearing nothing but a gown probably would not say "I've shit my pants."

The verb tense used is the *present perfect* and technically should take the past participle **shat**: "I think I have just shat myself." But in modern usage "shit" can be used as the past particle instead.

Comment: "shat" is a relatively modern (18th century) invention. It has no basis in etymology, and was probably intended to be humourous (like kids inventing "yote" as the past tense of "yeet")  It is technically more correct to use "I've shit..." but does anybody care about technical accuracy when they are using vulgar language?

Comment: @JamesK ...or, you know, _right after_ they shat themselves?

Comment: Isn't it a bit sexist to suppose that those who aren't wearing 'pants' are naked below the waist? I know about the the US/UK pants/trousers thing.

Comment: ""shit" can be used as past participle" ... and as adjective and as adverb.

Comment: _"if one is not wearing pants, it's more likely to shit the floor rather than oneself"_ Be very careful about the definition of "pants" here, as there are Br/Am differences.

Comment: @Flater - also northern/southern English differences. Up north here (England) they say 'pants' for trousers. Down south, men's 'pants' are underpants, like e.g. boxer shorts. Ladies wear knickers.

Comment: I didn't even know "shat" is a (valid) word till I came here...

Answer (score 11):

You ask about the correct usage of, “I’ve sh—.”  I took you as asking about the past participle.  If you only meant to Bowdlerize, I hope you still find this interesting.

James K had an excellent comment pointing out that *shat* is not widely-used.  [In fact, it started as a joke only a few centuries ago.](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shit)  You’ll more commonly hear, in America, “He’s shit himself.”  You’ll also hear, “He **shitted** his pants when he heard,” and perhaps “He’s shitted.”  I’ve personally never heard people where I live say *shat*, but Google Ngrams says that *shat* is nine times more common than *shitted*, so my experience isn’t typical.  *Shite* caught on in England too late to make it over to the colonies, but was more common in Scotland and Ireland.

Most irregular verbs that form the past tense with a vowel change used to be what are called strong verbs in Old English.  A clue that *shit*/*shat* is not really one of them: its past participle is not **shitten* or **shatten*, so it does not match the patterns of *bite*/*bit*/*bitten* or *eat*/*ate*/*eaten*.  Neither is it **shut*, like *swing*/*swang*/*swung* or *stink*/*stank*/*stunk*.

There are, though, two other common verbs just like *shit*/*shat*/*shat*.  That’s why it was funny to pretend to care about using proper grammar for profanity, and on top of that be ridiculously wrong.  (*My Fair Lady* and *Pygmalion* are famous plays that mock how snobbish the English upper class used to be about how people spoke.)  Eventually, though, everybody forgot that it started as a joke.

Those verbs got the way they are by very different paths.  There’s *spit*/*spat*/*spat*, which began as a regular verb with the conjugations *spit*/*spitted*/*spitted*.  The two dental consonants T and D in *-tted* ran into each other and became *-t*.  It’s called a dental consonant because, when you make the sound *t*, your tongue is by your upper teeth.  The people who were in such a hurry also started moving their tongues there sooner, while they were still saying the vowel before the T.  Moving the tongue to the front of the mouth like this fronted the vowel, like *meet*/*met*/*met*, *fight*/*fought*/*fought*. or *shoot*/*shot*/*shot*.  When I say the *it* in *spit*, with my American accent, my tongue starts a short distance above my teeth and moves down. When I say the *at* in *spat*, my tongue barely moves vertically at all, although I do move it forward to touch my upper front teeth.  Or, to look at it another way, my tongue moves the same distance from saying SP to saying T, and I say a vowel with my tongue somewhere in between, but I move my tongue further before I say the A in *spat* than I do before I say the I in *spit*. All those other examples had the vowel get shorter too, as people said it faster, but the I in *spit* is already short.

There’s also *sit*/*sat*/*sat*. *Sit* used to be a strong verb with a past participle *seten*, which disappeared.  This might be because *seten* sounded just like the past participle of *set*, which also changed, or by analogy with *spit*.

Another way *shit*/*shat*/*shat* might have come about, but didn’t, is as a different class of strong verbs like *sing*/*sang*/*sung* (or my other examples above).  If there had once been a hypothetical *shit*/*shat*/**shut*, the last form might have sounded too much like the actual verb *shut* and disappeared like *seten*.

There are other paradigms as well. *slit* used to be *slit*/*slitted*/*slitten*, but is now either *slit*/*slit*/*slit* or *slit*/*slitted*/*slitted*.

*Shit* is actually just like *fit*, *knit*, *split* or *quit*.  They once were regular verbs that ended in T, added *-ed*, and doubled the T so we would know to say *itt* and not *ite*, forming *shitted*.  Some people but not others clipped the ending *-tted* to *-t*. Not everybody did, so the regular form did not disappear completely, unlike with the word *hit*. Long vowels became short, for example *light*/*lit*/*lit*, but vowels that were already short usually did not change.  *Spat* is an exception, and people also say both *spit*/*spit*/*spit* and *spit*/*spitted*/*spitted*.

Only certain words from Old English went through this process.  The Danes reached England early enough that there are a few Norse words that did, such as *cast*.  There are also a few French words like *hurt*.  Any words that entered the language more recently, such as *submit*, *permit* and *benefit*, are regular.

*Shat* is not the only verb that became irregular in modern English by imitating an irregular verb it rhymes with.  Some people say “I dove” instead of “I dived.”  This is based on the conjugation of *strive*, but since that’s an authentic strong verb, it’s conjugated *strive*/*strove*/*striven* (although the I in *strive* is now pronounced ai and the I in *striven* as a short I).  You can tell because the copycat only coined the word *dove*, and there is no **diven*.

This won’t help you remember which verb works one way and which one works another way.  There’s no rule here, just a bunch of exceptions to memorize.  I think this is interesting.  But, on behalf of my ancestors, I apologize.

Comment: I've heard people use both "shit" and "shat" as a past tense, but _never_ "shitted".

Comment: @NickMatteo [*Shat* is nine times more common than *shitted* in the Google Ngrams corpus.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shat%2Cshitted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshitted%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshitted%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @NickMatteo Personally, the first time I ever encountered the word *shat* was in a translation of *One Hundred Years of Solitude*, and I remember being perplexed by it. So I should edit.

Comment: I agree, and the dictionary confirms this answer. The dictionary cites the possible past tense and past participles for this vulgar verb as ending in "-it," "-at," and "-itted." I will say that when using this vulgarity, saying "-at" smacks of being highbrow at being lowbrow, like you're choosing to be an unrefined, no-class, crass pig, but goddammit, you're choosing to be so in a manner that accurately reflects your actual education, refinement and class.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman It started out as, if I’m getting it and not projecting, ironic mockery of the upper class and their snobbery about how people should talk.

Comment: I suspect that "shat" didn't just stick around due to people forgetting it was a joke. As the word became more acceptable, people found it useful to have a different form for the past and present. While "shitted" isn't exactly hard to say, it's a bit harder than "shat," with that quick tongue movement between two dental consonants (unless one's accent glottalizes the /t/). That quick movement also possibly contributed to "shit" being its own past tense form in the first place--normally vulgarities,. like neologisms, take on the standard -ed form, e.g. fucked, bitched, damned, dicked, etc.

Comment: @trlkly Most verbs like *shit* (native English weak verb, one syllable, ends in a dental consonant, short vowel) have a past conjugation that either is the same as the stem, or is regular, though. Many have both forms.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but: as much as I find this answer useful and interesting, I can't help but notice that it doesn't answer the question that was asked. It's more like a (very long) comment on an issue that was raised by another answer. We should definitely keep it, but I suggest to [edit] it and add a disclaimer at the top, so that readers know what to expect and may decide whether they want to read it. Otherwise it should be moved to a separate question. Sorry for being pedantic!

Comment: Where is the question about the past tense form that this seems to be an answer to?

Comment: @Barmar The question asks about “I’ve sh—,” so it’s about the past participle.

Comment: @Davislor I interpreted the "--" to be avoiding writing a rude word, not a blank for you to fill in with the answer. The question is about whether the sentences are equivalent with the two different direct objects.

Comment: @Barmar Well, several people have found it helpful, at least.

Comment: @Davislor My comment is more restricted than that. It must have the /ɪ/ vowel. The words I considered were sit, fit, hit, knit, and quit, which become sat, fit, hit, knit, and quit in the past tense. None are regular, so it makes sense that "shitted" also didn't really catch on. The choice between "shit" and "shat" is, I believe, because people preferred having a different word for the past tense once such a word became available.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica All right, I’ve added a disclaimer.